# objectivec NSURLSessionDownloadTask

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I viewed this code here,

https://www.raywenderlich.com/67081/cookbook-using-nsurlsession

```
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadPhotoTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
downloadTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
UIImage *downloadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location]];
}];
```

I hope this code connects to the server two times, so the images are loading slow. I just want to know how to use NSURLSessionDownloadTask to download image by hitting the server only once.

Comment: That code wouldn't connect to the server twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I hope this code connects to the server two times, so the images are downloading slow.

The code you show does **not** connect to the server and download twice, though it is easy to see why it might appear to do so.

So if you are looking for a reason why your download is slow and think it might be due to a double download, then it is not.

If you've just misunderstood the code here is an outline of how it operates:

- The code is a *download task*. Such a task downloads a URL and stores its contents into a temporary file.
- When the download task is complete it calls its completion handler passing it the URL of the *local temporary file* (**not** the original remote URL).
- The completion handler reads the contents of the local file into an `NSData` object using `dataWithContentsOfURL:`. That method can also be used to read a remote URL, which is why a quick look might result in someone thinking this is a repeat of the download, but it is not - it is reading a local file.

You might ask why a temporary file is used rather than the URL content being delivered directly as an `NSData` object? The answer is that can be using a *data task*, you will need to study the documentation for the pros'n'cons of download versus data tasks.

For more detail read Apple's [NSURLSession Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:) and [URL Session Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165-BCICJDHA).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple use afnetworking ..

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
    _imageView.image = responseObject;

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Image error: %@", error);
}];
[requestOperation start];
```

Comment: thank you vaibhav, I'm new to iOS and  I wish to know whether is it possible to do it , without using AFNetworking

Comment: @Sujananth you cannot be so rigid in sence of programming it is my personal experience of using **afnetworking** which is faster then other without any confusion .. **still you want to go with your issue i strongly recommend you to read before you implement any code** ..